# Trouble with adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

i have the next table "dialogs":

[image: dialogs]

and now i want add the next fk:

```
alter table dialogs add constraint dias_fk foreign key(Receiver) references users (Surname);
```

but got an error:

**Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint**

users table:

[image]

i know, that i can create fk only with primary key column in the "users" and "dialogs" table, but i've got auto_increment column, that must be pk. i can't create two primaries in code, but with altering table with workbench utilities that looks like i've create two primaries without errors.

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: the table that is the parent (if you will) needs an index on the column. It can even be left-most in a composite index.

Comment: @Drew ok, i've create index: http://clip2net.com/s/3pHzALR and what i must do tne next?

Comment: well, you need to make sure the referenced table has the data in it that supports the FK creation. Afterall, you are saying the data must be there. So without it, it is a non-starter. And look into the character set issue.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept answers if appropriate. Even feedback such as "this is junk and makes no sense". We use that  feedback, and cheers us on to help the next guy, regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

From the mysql manual page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.
>
> When foreign_key_checks is enabled, which is the default setting,
>   character set conversion is not permitted on tables that include a
>   character string column used in a foreign key constraint. The
>   workaround is described in Section 13.1.6, “ALTER TABLE Syntax”.
>
> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

So your issue is not one to focus on PK's, but rather left-most indexes. Note too that the **45** is not crucial from reading the above. But the **character set** certainly is a potential problem.

The other issue that is obvious but often I forget, is that the *referenced* table must have a data state that honors such an FK creation to begin with. Meaning, the data must be there such that after the call to alter the *referencing* table, it could be said that the FK is honored by the *referenced* table.

### Illustration of my last point

```
create table referenced
(   -- a.k.a. parent
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(45) not null,
    key(thing)
    -- ok I have 2 indexes not
);
insert referenced (thing) values ('fish');

create table referencing
(   -- a.k.a. child
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(45) not null,
    key(thing)
    -- ok I have 2 indexes not
);
insert referencing (thing) values ('fish'),('frog');

alter table referencing add constraint thing_fk foreign key(thing) references referenced (thing);
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`so_gibberish`.`#sql-6cc_41`, CONSTRAINT `thing_fk`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`thing`) REFERENCES `referenced` (`thing`))  0.859 sec

**what to do?**

well, clean up referenced, afterall.

```
insert referenced(thing) values('frog');

alter table referencing add constraint thing_fk foreign key(thing) references referenced (thing);
```

**-- happy times**